# Can you explain extra padding on the 3rd table when content has overflow hidden and inline-block?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Adding "display: inline-block" and "overflow: hidden" to elements seems to change their margin inside tables. It seems to be related to vertical-align, but why "overflow: hidden" even if only horizontal, makes a difference? Safari doesn't seem to be affected.

http://jsbin.com/ribezifoli/1/edit?html,css,output

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 10px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
}

.one span {
  display: inline-block;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.two span {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.three span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* vertical-align: top; */
}
```

```html
<table class="one">
  <tr>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="two">
  <tr>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="three">
  <tr>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
    <td><span>hello</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Why make a bin but not a snippet? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 2):

From the very last paragraph of [section 10 of CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#leading):

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

The baselines of the inline-blocks with `overflow: hidden`, therefore, are their bottom margin edges, and the extra padding you see is space that's reserved for typographic descenders beneath the baseline that the inline-blocks reside on. The text *within* these inline-blocks is on separate baselines, unrelated to their parent table cells.

Comment: Weird. It behaves differently in Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

Comment: @aristidesfl: Safari historically has issues with this.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of vertical alignment.

Add `vertical-align: top` to `.three span` and it'll snap into place.